# Cut a field and LIKE search the parts

Tags: python, sql, string, sqlite

I have a list of names (actually, authors) stored in a sqlite database. Here is an example:

```
João Neres, Ruben C. Hartkoorn, Laurent R. Chiarelli, Ramakrishna Gadupudi, Maria Rosalia Pasca, Giorgia Mori, Alberto Venturelli, Svetlana Savina, Vadim Makarov, Gaelle S. Kolly, Elisabetta Molteni, Claudia Binda, Neeraj Dhar, Stefania Ferrari, Priscille Brodin, Vincent Delorme, Valérie Landry, Ana Luisa de Jesus Lopes Ribeiro, Davide Farina, Puneet Saxena, Florence Pojer, Antonio Carta, Rosaria Luciani, Alessio Porta, Giuseppe Zanoni, Edda De Rossi, Maria Paola Costi, Giovanna Riccardi, Stewart T. Cole
```

It's a string. My goal is to write an efficient "analyser" of name. So I basically perform a LIKE query:

```
' ' || replace(authors, ',', ' ') || ' ' LIKE '{0}'.format(my_string)
```

I basically replace all the commas with a space, and insert a space at the end and at the beginning of the string. So if I look for:

```
% Rossi %
```

I'll get all the items, where one of the authors has "Rossi" as a family name. "Rossi", not "Rossignol" or "Trossi".

It's an efficient way to look for an author with his family name, because I'm sure the string stored in the database contains the family names of the authors, unaltered.

But the main problem lies here: "Rossi" is, for example, a very common family name. So if I want to look for a very particular person, I will add his first name. Let's assume it is "Jean-Philippe". "Jean-Philippe" can be stored in the database under many forms: "J.P Rossi", "Jean-Philippe Rossi", "J. Rossi", "Jean P. Rossi", etc.

So I tried this:

```
% J%P Rossi %
```

But of course, It matches everything containing a J, then a P, and finally rossi. It matches the string I gave as an example. (Edda De Rossi)

So I wonder if there is a way to cut the string in the query, on a delimiter, and then match each piece against the search pattern.

Of course I'm open to any other solution. My goal is to match the search pattern against each author name.

Comment: Storing delimited lists of values is problematic and inefficient.  You should normalize the data, splitting those author names into multiple rows.

Comment: By rows you mean in the string ? By adding \n ?

Comment: No in different rows in the database

Comment: I have more than 16000 items, each with as many authors as I gave in my example. I think I would have perf issues.

Comment: Having to handle the entire string is a performance issue *now*.

Comment: True. Ok what I do now and what is working, is to refine the results of the sql query afterwards. I loop over the author fields for all the items returned by the first query, and filter them with python. But I'm still open for better solutions.